# Как получить список измененных файлов в GIT?

Tags: git, git-log

Нужно получить список измененных файлов, при этом вывести только те, которые совпадают с имеющимися.

Существует команда с параметрами: `git log --name-only`, которая выводит список измененных файлов, но их очень много. У меня есть свой список файлов (таблицы, пакеты и т.д.), можно ли их как-то сравнить, чтобы в конечном итоге вывело только те объекты, которые совпали при сравнении?

---

**перенесено из комментария:**

Работаю в *ms/windows* с помощью GIT BASH.

В данном случае нужно показать объекты Oracla, такие как view, tables, packages. Например, вывод команды

```
git log --name-only
```

показывает автора комита, дату, коммент и сам файл с путем:

```
rollback/oracle/scheme/tables/T_COL_NAMES.sql
rollback/oracle/scheme/tables/T_NUM_VAL.sql
```

Объектами (частями имени файла) являются: `T_COL_NAMES` и `T_NUM_VAL`, и таких очень много. Но у меня есть перечень своих. Допустим, мой объект — это `T_NUM_VAL`.

Каким образом я могу задать свои объекты (часть имени файла), чтобы команда вывела только их, а остальные отсеяла?

Comment: Если под linux'ом сидите, то попробуйте утилиту grep

Comment: что за объекты у Вас в git?

Comment: предполагаю, что разыскивается команда `git status`. возможно, с параметром `--untracked-files=no`. // но всё-таки вопрос лучше конкретизировать. пример какой-то привести того, что требуется.

Comment: Сижу под виндой работаю через GIT BASH.
В данном случае нужно вытащить объекты Oracla такие как view, tables, packages.
Например вывод команды git log --name-only:
показывает автора комита, дату, коммент и сам объект с путем:
rollback/oracle/scheme/tables/T_COL_NAMES.sql
rollback/oracle/scheme/tables/T_NUM_VAL.sql
Объектами являются: T_COL_NAMES и T_NUM_VAL и таких очень много, но у меня есть перечень своих
Допустим мой объект это T_NUM_VAL.
Каким образом я могу задать свои объекты чтобы оно вывело только их, а остальные отсеяло?
Этого не понимаю...

Answer (score 2):

для вывода информации о коммитах, в которых изменялись файлы, содержащие в названии, например, строки `T_COL_NAMES` и `T_NUM_VAL`, можно воспользоваться примерно такой командой (`--` служит для отделения опций от параметров, которые могут начинаться, как и опции, с символа <kbd>-</kbd>):

```
$ git log -- *T_COL_NAMES* *T_NUM_VAL*
```

а чтобы в вывод попали и сами имена файлов, надо добавить (как вы уже и делали) опцию `--name-only`:

```
$ git log --name-only -- *T_COL_NAMES* *T_NUM_VAL*
```

или даже `--name-status` — в этом случае перед именем файла будет стоять условное обозначение: `M` — модифицирован. `A` — добавлен (added), `D` — удалён (deleted) и т.д.:

```
$ git log --name-status -- *T_COL_NAMES* *T_NUM_VAL*
```

---

подробности смотрите в [документации](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) к команде `git log`. в частности, по поводу обозначений статусов файлов — в описании опции `--diff-filter`.